# Why is the content of my js file replaced by html code?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I am trying to use functions in dcsubscriber.js:

[image]

However, when running the website, the content of dcsubscriber.js is replaced completely by some odd html code:

[image]

---

Update:

I use Admin panel to add html code from Markdown editor

[image]

Comment: how did you call these functions, can you share some code ?

Comment: hi @AurelioLIMAFERREIRA please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) 
Put your js file inside static folder and use them like this :

```
<Helmet>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="/test.js" />
</Helmet>
```

Comment: Hi, I am using React-Helmet, that is where I load the separated dcsubscriber.js file which contains the updateSubscription() method.

Comment: so just need to put your js file inside static folder

Comment: yep, this is where I put the dcsubscriber.js right now, but once I put it under the static folder, then I am not able to access to process.env.<ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE>.

Comment: hi @Aurelio, to see more details about no access to environmental variables,please have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63611042/how-to-use-environmental-or-os-variables-in-self-created-javascript-files  thanks

Comment: need to check if you can use netlify lambda function (/.netlify/functions/hello) with your script

Comment: yep, I can confirm that I can use the lambda function from the dcsubscriber.js. The lambda function is hosted separately so anyone can call it anyway.